# Express Generator not generating anything

Tags: node.js, express

I recently switched to node.js and have been trying to use the Express Generator module to generate an app, but after:

```
sudo npm install express-generator -g
express -h
```

I simply get no output. Nothing. It is installed, but it just doesn't output anything.

```
n3utrin0x@pandoras-box:~/proj/temp$ express -h
n3utrin0x@pandoras-box:~/proj/temp$ express -v
n3utrin0x@pandoras-box:~/proj/temp$ express
n3utrin0x@pandoras-box:~/proj/temp$ sudo express -h
n3utrin0x@pandoras-box:~/proj/temp$
```

I'm on Ubuntu 15.04 x64.